# Bitmap loosing reference on static hashmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, hashmap

I got an static hashmap in order to be able to instantiate multiple times the same class, and the hashmap will hold all the key-value reference.

```
class A {
     public static final Map<String,Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();

     // methods
}
```

So on every instance of the class `A`, when you call `map.get(KEY)`, you'll always get the same bitmap. I'm getting an "Released unknown bitmap reference" `IllegalStateException` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if Android needs memory, it deletes some variables.
So if your app is having a lot of big vars like Bitmaps in static variable, they can be deleted sometimes by the system. I had this problem with an app. The only solution I found is that you have to check on your getter if the object exists, if it doesn't, you'll have to recreate it...

Comment: +1 for noting that Android sometime clears out statics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling .recycle() on the bitmap? 
If so when you come to get the bitmap from the hashmap it will no longer exist and throw that exception